# Find coordinates of a Canny Edge Image - OpenCV & python

Tags: python, opencv, coordinates

I want to save in a list the coordinates of all edges that the openCV detect, I succeed in showing the edges on screen (on the subscribed photo), and I don't know how to save the coordinates (all the white lines).
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 20):

You have found the edges, now you need to find **where** those edges are located.

(I did not use the image provided by you, I rather used a sample image on my desktop :D )

The following lines gives you those coordinates:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('Messi.jpg', 0)
edges = cv2.Canny(img, 100, 255)     #--- image containing edges ---
```

Now you need to find coordinates having value more than 0

```
indices = np.where(edges != [0])
coordinates = zip(indices[0], indices[1])
```

- I used the `numpy.where()` method to retrieve a tuple `indices` of two arrays where the first array contains the x-coordinates of the white points and the second array contains the y-coordinates of the white pixels.

`indices` returns:

```
(array([  1,   1,   2, ..., 637, 638, 638], dtype=int64),
 array([292, 298, 292, ...,  52,  49,  52], dtype=int64))
```

- I then used the `zip()` method to get a list of tuples containing the points.

Printing `coordinates` gives me a list of coordinates with edges:

```
[(1, 292), (1, 298), (2, 292), .....(8, 289), (8, 295), (9, 289), (9, 295), (10, 288), (10, 289), (10, 294)]
```

Comment: Only issue with this solution is that it returns one list of points, in order from top to bottom: what if you wanted multiple lists of contiguous points, such that you could use `cv2.drawContours` with them?